# Need to extract contents depending upon its title using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to extract text depending on the title, let's say in the below code, I need to display Experience field. Like, let's assume I have a text file as ab.text which has data like:

```
Name: xyz
Experience: 
123 company 2016-2017
567 company 2017-2018
yzx company 2018-2019

Skills:
Python, MachineLearning, Java.
```

Now i need to read this text file and display only the texts that is under experience field. 
Note: The order of Name , expereince and skills may vary.
I am new to python please help me on this.

Expected Output:

```
Experience: 
123 company 2016-2017
567 company 2017-2018
yzx company 2018-2019
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `re` module and parse the text with it:

```
data = '''Name: xyz
Experience:
123 company 2016-2017
567 company 2017-2018
yzx company 2018-2019

Skills:
Python, MachineLearning, Java.'''

import re

#Step 1. Split the string
s = [g.strip() for g in re.split('^(\w+):', data, flags=re.M) if g.strip()]
# s = ['Name', 'xyz', 'Experience', '123 company 2016-2017\n567 company 2017-2018\nyzx company 2018-2019', 'Skills', 'Python, MachineLearning, Java.']

#Step 2. Convert the splitted string to dictionary
d = dict(zip(s[::2], s[1::2]))
# d = {'Name': 'xyz', 'Experience': '123 company 2016-2017\n567 company 2017-2018\nyzx company 2018-2019', 'Skills': 'Python, MachineLearning, Java.'}

print(d['Experience'])
```

Prints:

```
123 company 2016-2017
567 company 2017-2018
yzx company 2018-2019
```

Comment: This usage of re is overkill, especially just to extract the contents of Experience

Comment: @CodeDaddy, but IMHO it creates a structure to the data using `:` which is good. He can use the other data if he needs it as well. Writing code to work for a very very specific use-case is like a wastage of time and resource :-); you should question the data source instead. Optimize only if required.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you've set is not super well defined. But based on the example file you provided the below code will work. You should learn something about file i/o, list methods and list comprehensions to understand more the code below. I've tried to structure it in a way that each time you run a line you can investigate what the line does so the code doesn't seem like magic.

```py
f = open('C:/ab.text') # change ot the path of your file
contents = f.read() #read the contents
contents = contents.split('\n') # turn the read object into a list
contents = [x.strip() for x in contents] #remove whitespace from elements
# below we concatentate the list so it starts at the Experience: row
contents = contents[contents.index('Experience:'):] 
# make a list of all the lines containing colons ':'

colon_places = [i for i,x in enumerate(contents) if x.find(':')>0] 

#if there is only one colon it will be at the start from 'Experience:'
if colon_places == [0]:
    contents=  contents
#if there is more than one, we only want to go as far as the second
elif len(colon_places) > 1:
    contents = contents[0:colon_places[1]]

#finally, we throw out the header 'Experience' and any empty rows
Experience = [x for x in contents if x  not in ['Experience:', '']]
```

I hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick

**Code**

```
matches = re.findall('^Experience:.*[(\d+ \w+ \d+\-\d+)\n]+$', text, re.M)
for match in matches:
    print(match.strip())
    print()
```

**Explanation**

> ^Experience

signifies that our match should start with word `Experience`

> [(\d+ \w+ \d+-\d+)\n]+

will match the pattern `123 company 2016-2017` one or more number of times

> $

at the end indicates that the pattern ends once when the pattern `123 company 2016-2017` is exhausted

> re.M

indicates that our input text is a multilined string and not a single, long text